# A problem with Fourier transforms

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, fourier-transform

Consider 2 real functions $f, g: \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ and $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$. First I thought that the following equality was true
\begin{align}
&\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dtg(t)\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}d\omega e^{-i\omega t}(i\omega)^\alpha\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} d\tau  e^{i\omega \tau}f(\tau) \\
    = &(-1)^\alpha \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} d\tau f(\tau)\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} d\omega e^{-i\omega \tau} (i\omega)^\alpha\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dt e^{i\omega t} g(t) \\
\end{align}
where we made the substitution $\omega \to -\omega$.

However on further inspection I noticed that the left side is real (can be checked by taking the complex conjugate) but the right hand side is not (since $(-1)^\alpha = e^{i\pi\alpha}$). So my question is what am I missing?

Edit:

I think the fault is when I do the substitution $(-1)^\alpha (i\omega)^\alpha \stackrel{?}{=} (-i\omega)^\alpha$. But then how do I isolate the -?

Comment: Shouldn't it be $e^{i\omega \tau}$ after the substitution? Then if you don't factor out the $(-1)^\alpha$ you can use that $-i$ is the conjugate of $i$.

Comment: I swapped some integration orders as well (which I am also not sure if I am allowed to do). First the order is $t \to \omega \to \tau$ but after the equal I swapped them such that the order becomes $\tau \to \omega \to t$ and then renamed $t \longleftrightarrow \tau$.

Comment: If you want to swap the order of integration for a function $f(x)$ you have to ensure $\vert f(x) \vert$ has a finite integral on the same interval. Did you check that?

Comment: I came to the first form of this integral with an assumption that it converges for 'nice enough' functions, so I should be able to swap them right.

Comment: The "nice enough" condition is that $\int \vert f(x) \vert$ has to be bounded on $(-\infty , \infty)$. I don't think that's the case here since $\vert e^{i \omega \tau} \vert = 1$ and the monomial term is unbounded.

Comment: For integer, $n \implies \int_{-\infty}^\infty dt g(t)\frac{d^n}{dt^n}f(t) = (-1)^n\int_{-\infty}^\infty dt f(t)\frac{d^n}{dt^n}g(t)$, which would be a repeated part. int. where the boundaries vanish since my assumption was that $f, g \in L_2(\mathbb(R))$. Proving this, you can either write this directly as derivatives or write the monomial term as $\delta^{(n)}(t-\tau)$ (defined through part. Int. in distribution sense). For this last method you have to swap integrals again so I thought I could see that monomial part as some distribution again, ignoring the infinity of the single integal.

Comment: Vanishing boundaries should be sufficient to justify rearrangements so it's probably not that. My next guess would that there is a sign error in one of the intermediate steps. They're typically subtle and the issue seems to be sign related.

Comment: The $(-1)^\alpha$ comes from the substitution (see after the Edit:... in the question).

Comment: Right, but it should $e^{i\omega \tau}$ not $e^{-i\omega \tau}$ after the substitution. What else did you do to get this form?

Comment: Is it? I made a mistake in putting that I swapped $t$ and $\tau$. I just made the substitution. Sorry for that confusion (it was on paper that I did but then I left it out here since I thought it would be just confusing).

Comment: I saw that you did the substitution $t = \tau$ but that doesn't give a $-1$ differential term like the $\omega = -\omega$ substitution.

Comment: My bad again, I should have not included 'in the second line'. I just get the equality by doing the $\omega$ substitution.